# Leaflet zoom to polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, esri-leaflet

I receive a polygon layer in *Leaflet* via *ESRI REST*. (similar to [here](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/styling-feature-layer-polygons.html) )
I want to have a menu where I can zoom to specific polygons. (one button per polygon)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be quite easy by using the `onEachFeature` option of the [`L.esri.featureLayer`](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/feature-layer.html), combined with shapes [`getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-getbounds) and map [`fitBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds).

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<p>List of features:</p>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

function myOnEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var li = document.createElement("li"),
        a = document.createElement("a");

    // Create the "button".
    a.innerHTML = "some text, possibly using feature.properties";
    a.href = "#";
    a.myLayer = layer; // Store a reference to the actual layer.
    a.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the link from scrolling the page.
        map.fitBounds(this.myLayer.getBounds()); // Move to the shape!
    });
    li.appendChild(a);
    list.appendChild(li);
}

L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: 'someUrl',
    onEachFeature: myOnEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/47/